# What does the following snippet mean?

Tags: java

```
 TestClass.this.onError(error);
```

I think this is the keywork in java, how can a classname follows with this? Is this a special 
feature of java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a way of accessing the implicit instance of an enclosing class from within an inner class. For example:

```
public class Test {
    
    private final String name;
    
    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test("Jon");
        // Create an instance of NamePrinter with a reference to the new instance
        // as the enclosing instance.
        Runnable r = t.new NamePrinter();
        r.run();
    }    
    
    private class NamePrinter implements Runnable {
        @Override public void run() {
            // Use the enclosing instance's name variable
            System.out.println(Test.this.name);
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Java Language Specification section 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) for more about inner classes and enclosing instances, and [section 15.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) for the "qualified `this`" expression:

> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by explicitly qualifying the keyword this.
>
> Let `C` be the class denoted by `ClassName`. Let n be an integer such that `C` is the n'th lexically enclosing class of the class in which the qualified this expression appears.
>
> The value of an expression of the form `ClassName.this` is the n'th lexically enclosing instance of this.
>
> The type of the expression is `C`.

Comment: Jon, is there similar thing in C#?

Comment: @AdamLee: No - nested classes in C# don't work like inner classes in Java; there's no implicit enclosing instance. They work more like static nested classes in Java.

Answer (score 1):

From an inner class you are calling an instante method from the instance of TestClass that constains it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that from inner class of class, it will refer to the outer class.

For example if you have class Cat

```
public class Cat {

private int age;
private Tail tail;

public Cat(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.tail = new Tail();
}

class Tail {

    public void wave() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Cat.this.age; i++) {
            System.out.println("*wave*");
        }
    }

}

public Tail getTail() {
    return tail;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Cat(10).getTail().wave();
}

}
```